# call openshift rest api to get api token

Tags: ajax, rest, oauth, openshift, openshift-origin

I want to get an API token for a specific user using openshift rest api. I have a web application which can be used by any user in my organization. I want to be able to authenticate the user in my application using an internal oauth service, after authentication, i want to authorize the user to be able to call openshift rest apis.

I have found 2 APIs, /authorize and /token which get called up to generate api tokens which can be sent as Bearer 'Token' in the REST APIs headers. But not able to find a way to call them. I have been facing CORS errors calling these APIs using AJAX request.

https://openshift-master.bruxelles.sodigital.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=openshift-browser-client&response_type=code

This url is internal to my organisation which authenticates the employees if not authenticated, and then displays a token on the web page. I want to be able to get that token.

Comment: When you say 'internal oauth service', is that the same oauth service that the OpenShift cluster is using to authenticate users? If yes, have you looked at https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy as suggested previously. When you use it to handle the authentication, one of the options it has is to enable it to pass the users access token through with the requests to the application behind it. That would give you access to the token.

Comment: adding to your comment on google groups, you had suggested to use service account tokens, but service account tokens are limited to projects, can I get a service account token that allows me to create projects as well? or is there any other provision to create a project using some permanent token.

Comment: When you use ``oauth-proxy`` for OpenShift, that likely would be giving you the user token, which should be able to create projects.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I looked into oauth-proxy, it's a little confusing for me. Do i have to create a pod on openshift and then use it?

Comment: You would deploy your application in OpenShift, but not create a public route for it. You would then deploy oauth-proxy in OpenShift, with a public route. The oauth-proxy would be configured to pass through traffic to your application. When you first hit the public URL for your application (actually the route of the auth-proxy), it would make you log in using your OpenShift credentials. Subsequent requests will then go straight through to your application, including the access token if you enable that to be passed by auth-proxy in a header to your application.

Comment: So while ever a user is accessing your application, via the oauth-proxy, you should have access to their user access token, which you can then do things on their behalf.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far @GrahamDumpleton, I've been assisting Ayush on this.  We've got something working with the proxy as a proper sidecar where we can get a token to call APIs with, but when we call certain API's, such as to create project, it fails.  any thoughts?  i suspect I need to use --openshift-delegate-urls to allow the master to decide what we can do, but the documentation on that is a bit 'ropey'.  if you've not used that particular parameter, then I'll just try a few things and I'm sure i'll eventually get it, just wondered if it was anything you've seen done before?

Comment: I have never used it myself. I am assuming the token you are given is equivalent to the user in what it can do. If it isn't and it is a distinct service account token related to a specific project, then it may not have appropriate rights to create projects. I am not able to look at this myself at the moment, so do keep me up to date.

Comment: I have sort of deployed both oauth-proxy, and my application in a pod. But now where do i get the access-token, is it there in the response of the apis i see in the network tab? or somewhere in the cookies?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I am not able to get access-token in the headers even if i pass --pass-access-token=true in the yaml file. Is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: Do you mean ``--pass-user-bearer-token`` option?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks for the help on this issue. We did solve the problem and the app works just fine. I just wanted to ask one thing, When i first hit the route, it takes me to the openshift login page. Can this login page be configured? By 'configured', we have set up our own keycloak server for authentication, since the openshift login also uses keycloak, can we make oauth-proxy use another client (created by us) so that we can control the access to the app we are creating?

Comment: No idea. Have never played with oauth-proxy myself yet, although is on the list, I just know a bit about what it does.